# Ionic Phonegap Facebook Native | Key Hash Error

Tags: facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-facebook-plugin

I'm building and app with Ionic.

I've followed [this article](https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/native-facebook-login-with-ionic-framework) about integrating my application with the native facebook sdk for a more pleasant experience of my users.

Unfortunately since today the facebook login gets stuck and keep responding with **"Invalid key hash. The key hash XXX does not match any stored key hashes..."**

I'm still running my app in development, I've never built it.

I've read all the possible articles about setting the key hash.

Tried:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

which should be for development, but I noticed that the key in response from this command isn't the same form the error I reported above.

I think my application is stuck with a wrong hash key that gets from I don't know where... Because it should get the key from the debug.keystore in ./android .

Also I tried to create an entirely new application copying only the www folder, repeated the steps of configuration from the article above but nothing changed. Same error, same wrong key hash reported from the error.

Don't really know what the issue could be.

My facebook app is LIVE, I'm on mac.

I run my application on my android phone through `ionic run android`

Comment: I am also facing the same problem for quite some time. You found anything ?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find anything... Neither on the slack community channel of Ionic.

Comment: Found a solution on this?